# How do i specify wcf behaviorExtension class type without the assembly version number?

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-3.5

I have a web app that uses a WCF service that utilizes a behaviorExtension like so:

```
<behaviorExtensions>
<add name="clientCredentialsExtension" type="Simon.Web.Giftcard.WCFSecurity.ClientCredentialsExtensionElement, Simon.Web.Giftcard, Version=1.0.3736.20411, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
</behaviorExtensions>
```

The problem is this web app's version changes with every compile (i think) and thus invalidating this entry.

How can I avoid having to change the version number every time I compile this?  Can I specify the extension in code somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<behaviorExtensions>
    <add 
        name="clientCredentialsExtension"         
        type="Simon.Web.Giftcard.WCFSecurity.ClientCredentialsExtensionElement, Simon.Web.Giftcard"/>
</behaviorExtensions>
```

Comment: No dice.  "Extension element 'clientCredentialsExtension' cannot be added to this element."

Answer (score 2):

If you are stuck with .NET 3.5 where the [configuration bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/wcf/feedback/details/216431/wcf-fails-to-find-custom-behaviorextensionelement-if-type-attribute-doesnt-match-exactly) is not fixed yet, the solution is to implement [IServiceBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.iservicebehavior.aspx) by your service. See [this article, example 6-15](http://codeidol.com/csharp/wcf/Faults/Error-Handling-Extensions/) .

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it's fixed in .Net 4.0 beta 2.  Not much use to me, who is stuck with 3.5.

http://connect.microsoft.com/wcf/feedback/details/216431/wcf-fails-to-find-custom-behaviorextensionelement-if-type-attribute-doesnt-match-exactly

Answer (score 0):

This annoying bug bit me before too.  I eventually changed all mine to build up in code instead of in the config.