# Referencing DLL in a version agnostic way from a behaviorExtension

Tags: .net, iis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do i specify wcf behaviorExtension class type without the assembly version number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518425/how-do-i-specify-wcf-behaviorextension-class-type-without-the-assembly-version-n)

In my web application hosted on IIS7 I have a project X referencing project Y (project reference in VS2010). I'm trying to add behaviorExtensions with types from Y in X's web.config without specifying version number.

I'm adding a behaviorExtension under System.ServiceModel.Extensions.

```
<behaviorExtensions>
<add name="serviceKeyBehavior" type="MyNS.ServiceSupport.ServiceKeyBehaviorExtensionElement, Analyst.API"/>
<add name="userNameClientCredentials" type="MyNS.ServiceSupport.UserNameClientCredentialsElement, Analyst.API" />
</behaviorExtensions>
```

I haven't been able to make it work without specifying e.g.

```
Version=3.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
```

at the end of the type attribute.

Usually just leaving out the version info above works fine.

If I change 
      `type="MyNS.ServiceSupport.ServiceKeyBehaviorExtensionElement, Analyst.API"`

to

`type="MyNS.ServiceSupport.ServiceKeyBehaviorExtensionElement, Analyst.API, Version=3.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"`

(3.2.1.0 == Current DLL version), it works.

Otherwise it claims it doesn't find the type:

> An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for
>   system.serviceModel/behaviors: Extension element 'serviceKeyBehavior'
>   cannot be added to this element. Verify that the extension is
>   registered in the extension collection at
>   system.serviceModel/extensions/behaviorExtensions. Parameter name:
>   element (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\xyz\web.config line 155)
>   Check eventlog (ID: 1265) for more information.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this blog post from 2008:

http://keyvan.io/configuration-error-for-custom-behavior-extensions-in-wcf

It seems to be a bug in WCF. 
I tried recompiling it with .Net framework 4.0 and then it works fine.

There is also a thread here at StackOverflow describing this which I didn't find before:

[How do i specify wcf behaviorExtension class type without the assembly version number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518425/how-do-i-specify-wcf-behaviorextension-class-type-without-the-assembly-version-n)