# How Can I Avoid Adding Assembly Version In web.config?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, configuration, web-config

I'm adding a custom endpoint behaviour to my WCF service with a class extended from `BehaviorExtensionElement` to initialise it. In my `web.config`, I add the following to register the behaviour extension:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Service.MyService">
        <endpoint address=""
                  behaviorConfiguration="endpointBehavior"
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  contract="Contracts.IMyService"/>
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="endpointBehavior">
          <logBehavior />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="logBehavior"
             type="MyNamespace.MyBehaviorExtensionElement, MyAssembly, Version=0.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
</system.serviceModel>
```

This works absolutely fine, but I have to specify the version of the assembly to get it to load. If I change the assembly reference to just `MyNamespace.MyBehaviorExtensionElement, MyAssembly` without the version/culture/token then the service fails to launch with the error:

> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for system.serviceModel/behaviors: Extension element 'logBehavior' cannot be added to this element.  Verify that the extension is registered in the extension collection at system.serviceModel/extensions/behaviorExtensions.
>   Parameter name: element

The final portion of my assembly version will change frequently as part of my build process. How can I avoid having to keep updating the `web.config` with the new version number every time the build version increments (which could be hundreds of times)?

Comment: dup : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518425/how-do-i-specify-wcf-behaviorextension-class-type-without-the-assembly-version-n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the restriction on fully specified class names has been removed in .net 4 or above.  Have you tried:

```
  <behaviorExtensions>
     <add name="logBehavior"
         type="MyNamespace.MyBehaviorExtensionElement, MyAssembly" />
  </behaviorExtensions>
```

I might be wrong!

Comment: I tried removing the version/language/token as in my answer, but this doesn't work. I'm using .Net 3.5 SP1 and can't upgrade to .Net 4.

Comment: Sorry, just did a fast scan of the question.  I think its impossible to do in 3.5

Comment: @AdamRodger - You answered your own question.  Your limited to this behavior because of the version of the .NET Framework your using.